# React router not working in cloud environment after deploying

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-router-v4, asp.net-core-3.1

After successful login, my react app goes blank even the routing path is correct in the browser URL. It is working fine in my local and on IIS server when I deployed my app on the Azure cloud the issue is observed.

My application is hosted as a .net core API application has react front end. By running npm run build command bundling the react sources and publishing into wwwwroot folder.

Able to see the login screen but unable to navigate into the app routes
Here is my application flow using router.

App.tsx

```
<Fragment >
        <ToastContainer position='bottom-right'/>
        
        <Provider store={store}>
        <OidcProvider store={store} userManager={userManagerObj}>
         <Router history={history} >
          <Route exact path='/' component={HomePage}/>
          <AppPreview/>
          <Route path='/checkUser' component={VerifyUser}/>
          <Route path='/callback' component={CallbackPage}/>
         </Router>
        </OidcProvider>
        </Provider>
    </Fragment>
```

Here is AppPreview.tsx where I am switching the components based on routes

```
<Route path={'/(.+)'} render={() => (
          <Fragment>
            <div id="outer-container">
              <HeaderInfo/> 
              <main id="page-wrap">
                <NavBar />
               <div className="display-info">
                <Switch>
                  <Route exact path='/welcome'  component={WelcomePage} />
                  <Route exact path='/param' component={ParamMgmt} />
                  <Route exact path='/test'  component={Test}/>
                  <Route component={NotFound} />
                </Switch>
                </div>
              </main>                
            </div>  
          </Fragment>          
          )}
        />
```

the Navbar.tsx has the navigation links as below

```
<Menu pageWrapId={ "page-wrap" } outerContainerId={ "outer-container" } isOpen={menuOpen}
        onStateChange={state => handleStateChange(state)}>
            <Link id="home" className="menu-item" to="/welcome" onClick={() => {closeMenu()}} >
                <Icon name="home" size="large" />Home</Link>                
            <Link id="parameter" className="menu-item" to="/param" onClick={() => {closeMenu()}}>
                <Icon name="setting" size="large"/>Param</Link>
            <Link id="Test" className="menu-item" to="/test" onClick={() => {closeMenu()}}>
                <Icon name="setting" size="large"/>Test</Link>
        </Menu>
```

Finally, able to see login screen but /welcome, /param, /test routing paths going blank when invoking in cloud env

Comment: You say /welcome, /param and /test paths go blank in the cloud environment.  Do the HeaderInfo and NavBar components render as expected or are they blank as well?

Comment: even they are going blank nothing is getting loaded.

Comment: Have you tried to simplifying things.  By that, I mean take /welcome, /param and /test out of AppPreview.tsx and add them directly into App.tsx

Comment: Yes tried it but the result is the same still getting blank page